# A simple DEVISE sign-up... Why doesn't this rspec/capybara test pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

A typical DEVISE create account page should redirect to a welcome page for new users

```
describe ArtistsController do

  render_views

   ....

describe "Sign UP should redirect to welcome page" do
  it "should redirect to welcome page on valid sign up", :js => true do
    visit destroy_artist_session_path #just to be sure we're logged out
    visit new_artist_registration_path
    fill_in 'Email', :with => 'newguy@newguy.com'
    fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
    fill_in 'Password confirmation', :with => 'password'
    click_link_or_button 'Sign up'
    #save_and_open_page <-- reveals we are still on the sign-up page
    page.should have_content("Welcome")

  end
end
```

I manually QA'd this scenario on my local machine and it works fine.  But the test doesn't seem to work; it does NOT continue to the welcome page.  The new user is NOT created in the DB.  There is no complaint by capybara that it cannot find the button or anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess by running `save_and_open_page` in the place where you commented it out you have ensured that email and password are properly filled in. It might be that click_link_or_button is not working for some reason - can you try to grab the button by `find("button[type='submit']").click` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it was connected to **subdomains**.

The session key was "lvh.me",
but tests were using "example.com" by default.

My test was submitting login form correctly, user was authenticated no problem, then Devise was redirecting to the home page in "example.com" domain, and the app was not able to find session data (which were under "lvh.me" key), and was redirecting back to login page w/o any flash messages or errors.

So if you are using subdomains, be sure to set up Capybara hosts *before* logging user in. Just for a case, here is what I do:

```
def go_to(subdomain)
  Capybara.app_host = "http://#{subdomain}.lvh.me"
  Capybara.server_port = 3000
  host! "#{subdomain}.lvh.me:3000"
end
```

Comment: I'm not using subdomains, but I do suspect that it's something with the sessions and redirection.  Where do I set that method?  What host and port is used for tests by default?

Comment: 1) session store - I have a config/initializers/session_store.rb file with the following content: MySuperApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store,:key => '_my_super_app_session', :domain => ".lvh.me"

Comment: 2) what host and port are used - I've figured this out from logs (you can set logging level to :info for test environment to make logs more concise), alternatively you probably can output some relevant info to the page (I think you can use 'request' rails standard object for this) and use save_and_open_page inside your tests.

Comment: by the way, there is also 'session' rails object, you can output this as well instead of step 1)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're being redirected back to the login page.

- Does the output of save_and_open_page container any flash messages?
- Have you checked the test.log for clues?
- Try set the Capybara driver to mechanize and you'll be able to watch what happens - it may help in tracking down the problem.

Comment: the output of save_and_open_page does not contain any flash messages.  The log doesn't not appear to attempt an insert, I don't see any errors.  How do I set capybara to mechanize?